# Sentence: This may be considered a conflict of interest, although I think it does not

Tags: word-choice

What is the correct grammar in this sentence?

> This may be considered a conflict of interest, although I think it does/is/... not.

My question is about the second part. Should I use "does," "is," or anything else?

Comment: If you can replace a piece of the first clause with the option, then it works. For example, "This *is not* considered a conflict of interest" carries the meaning you intend, so "is not" works. But "This * does not considered a ..." isn't grammatical, so "does not" doesn't work there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Lawrence's comment is similar to this answer, I hope this is clearer by focusing on the fact that you are talking about what verb can substitute for a verbal phrase.

Constructions of the form "This is considered/thought/deemed/asserted an X" are contractions of the equivalent form "This is considered/thought/deemed/asserted **to be** an X." Thus, the construction is qualifying a statement of identity and so can be summarized only by a form of the verb "to be."

More generally, Lawrence is correct that if you are considering whether a form of "be" or a form of "do" is the proper choice for summarizing a **verbal phrase**, ask which summarizing verb could **grammatically** substitute for the phrase.

"This **may be considered** a conflict of interest" can be altered grammatically to "This **is** a conflict of interest." It cannot be altered grammatically to "This **does** a conflict of interest."